# Real analysis - proof approach help

Tags: real-analysis

I am taking a course in Real Analysis this semester and thought I would work ahead a little bit.

I am just reading for the moment, but came across an interesting exercise, and was wondering if I could see how one of you would solve it.

***Assume that $A$ and $B$ are nonempty, bounded above, and satisfy $B⊆A$. Show $\sup B≤\sup A.$***

Not so much that the question perplexes me, but rather I wanted to see an example of a rigorous proof for this question.

Comment: Have you put any thought on it so far?

Comment: You should really try to tackle this yourself--you would find it rewarding, I think. Suppose to the contrary that $\sup B > \sup A$. Can you see how this forces the existence of an element of $B$ which is strictly greater than every element of $A$? And, if so, why this contradicts $B\subset A$?

Comment: I would try it directly, what is the definition of $\sup A$?

Comment: Have you tried to use contradiction?

Comment: This is pure logic: Any upper bound for $A$ is an upper bound for $B$, in particular $\sup A$ is an upper bound for $B$, and on and on.

Comment: @Jazz Thanks, it seems immediately obvious now! I have covered my eyes so as not to read any other responses until I give it a proper attempt myself :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have now attempted this by myself and will post my proof here for critique. I welcome the most prudent critiques you can offer.

Firstly, since $A$ and $B$ are nonempty, and bounded above, they satisfy the axiom of completeness and thus we know that $\sup A$ and $\sup B$ exist.

Since $B \subseteq A$, then for all $b \in B$ it follows that $b \in A$.
Thus $\sup A \geq b, \space \forall b \in B \subseteq A$

Secondly, if we define $z$ as any upper bound for $B$, then by definition
$\sup B \leq z$.

Since we have established that $\sup A$ is an upper bound for $B$,

then it is clear that $\sup B \leq \sup A$

$\text{QED} ^{\tiny{brah}}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Can you show that $\sup A$ is an upper bound for $B$?